# npm i Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1

Tags: javascript, node-gyp, gyp

I am trying to install modules on Windows 10 using npm 6.14.13 When I enter npm i I get:

```html
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\קלמן\\SellersLog\\sellerslog-server\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release\\canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\קלמן\\SellersLog\\sellerslog-server\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\קלמן\SellersLog\sellerslog-server\node_modules\canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\קלמן\SellersLog\sellerslog-server\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=C:\Users\קלמן\SellersLog\sellerslog-server\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\קלמן\SellersLog\sellerslog-server\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\קלמן\\SellersLog\\sellerslog-server\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"    
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\קלמן\SellersLog\sellerslog-server\node_modules\canvas
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\קלמן\Sellenode_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
npm WARN rollback Rolling back debug@3.2.6 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\קלמן\SellersLog\sellerslog-server\node_modules\needle\node_modules'     
npm WARN sellerslog-server@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! canvas@2.6.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@2.6.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I also get this beforehand, don't know if this is important:

```html
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v83-win32-unknown-ia32.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for canvas@2.6.1 and node@14.17.0 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
```

note: already tried windows-build-tools - didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on

> canvas-v2.6.1-node-v83-win32-unknown-ia32.tar.gz

and

> C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe

you're using a 32-bit Node.js.

Based on [this list](https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/tag/v2.6.1), prebuilt node-canvas binaries exist only for 64-bit Node.js binaries.

I'd recommend to uninstall your 32-bit Node.js and install a 64-bit one instead.

Comment: ty very much! any tips how to read these error logs in the future?

Comment: In this case, my chain of reasoning was that (a) it tried to fall back to building (it generally doesn't need to) (b) why did it do that? let's see the prebuilt releases and what it's trying to download – hmm, right, no ia32 in the list