# How do i resolve NPM install error code 1?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

is anyone able to advice/guide me through this? Do i have a binding.gyp package?

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Kayven Jong\Desktop\Roboape\roboape-main\node_modules\libpq
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.17.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.5 found at "C:\Users\Kayven Jong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.10.31402.337) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\Kayven Jong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Kayven Jong\\Desktop\\Roboape\\roboape-main\\node_modules\\libpq\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Kayven Jong\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\14.17.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Kayven Jong\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\14.17.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\Kayven Jong\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\Kayven Jong\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\14.17.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Kayven Jong\\Desktop\\Roboape\\roboape-main\\node_modules\\libpq',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Kayven Jong\\Desktop\\Roboape\\roboape-main\\node_modules\\libpq\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! 'pg_config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pg_config --libdir' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\Kayven Jong\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:351:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Kayven Jong\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Kayven Jong\Desktop\Roboape\roboape-main\node_modules\libpq
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: did you try `npm cache clean` before running `npm install`?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67772122/npm-i-error-gyp-failed-with-exit-code-1) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348482/npm-install-with-error-gyp-failed-with-exit-code-1/60860951) help?

Comment: Hi @MahdiAryayi thanks for replying. I have tried npm cache clean --force before npm install. However, the error still persist.

Comment: hi @MuhtasimUlfatTanmoy, neither of them work. im unable to perform npm update either. Have checked that my node is x64 too.